# Error 2002 al intentar conectar php a mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando acceder a una base de datos creados en mysql mediante xampp, la tengo creada como en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al principio ni me cargaba apache, tuve que cerrar el servicio NET STOP W3SVC que me ocupaba el puerto 80, y ya me funciona bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que desde php tengo la función así:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'pruebasbdxamp';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected to $dbname at $host successfully.";
} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
```

Puse otro usuario y contraseña para probar y nada,
el error que me da es:

> Could not connect to the database pruebasbdxamp :SQLSTATE[HY000]
> [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it.

¿Alguna idea de cómo conseguir que me conecte?

Comment: tiene pinta de que el archivo de configuracion de mysql my.cnf tenga configurado que no admita conexiones externas. Mira el archivo y cambia `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` y comenta el de `skip-networking`. luego reinicia el servicio de mysql y prueba  a ver si conectas

Comment: # Change here for bind listening
bind-address="0.0.0.0" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

así lo tengo puesto ahora y tampoco funciona, mismo error

Comment: PUEDE SER que estoy cargando mi web que está en un servidor y la peticion de la base de datos está en localhost, y acceder desde fuera(internet) a mi localhost, no le deja... puede que sea eso... si es así como puedo solucionarlo....

Comment: Has comentado el `skip-networking`?

Comment: si, estaba comentado de base... creo que es por lo que he dicho, que la web y el php lo tengo hosteado en un servidor y la base de datos está en mi pc personal y accedo desde localhost... por eso no puede comunicarse desde fuera a mi localhost... y no se como hacerlo...

Comment: Si la BD no está en el mismo servidor que la aplicación web, entonces tienes que crear un usuario en la BD con la dirección del webserver: `pruebaphp@ip_del_servidor_web` (mira la primera imagen). Y por supuesto, en el script PHP ya no iría `localhost` como nombre de servidor, si no la dirección de la BD. Si esta aplicación va a ser pública, recomiendo no exponer el servidor de la BD a la calle, por lo tanto crea el usuario con el IP específico del webserver como ya expliqué.

Comment: bueno al final pillé un host gratuito de mysql y con esos datos accedí desde mi php y listo... lo necesitaba para aprender pero viendo que no puedo acceder desde fuera de mi localhost pues con esto me apaño... gracias!!